# ") was unexpected at this time." What am I doing wrong?

Tags: windows, batch-file, error-handling

So, when I run the following script I get ") was unexpected at this time." right as it hits the first 'for' statement.

The script is intended to correct the numbering structure of folders in 'database', with the numbers increasing from newest to oldest (starting at 0).
The folder structure in 'database' just needs to be named similarly to the following: "1 - 2_12_2017" or "34 - 1_14_2017".

Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong?

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "dbpth=C:\database"
set cnt=-1
cd %dbpth%
set "fy=unset"
set "fm=unset"
set "fd=unset"
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('dir /b /a:d /o:-n "%dbpth%\*"') do (
    for /f "delims=1234567890-_ " %%B in ("%%A") do (if not "%%B" == "" goto skp)
    set "str=%%A"
    set "str=!str:~-10!"
    set "str=!str: =!"
    set "str=!str:-=!"
        set "ys=unset"
        set "ms=unset"
        set "ds=unset"
    for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=_" %%F in ("!str!") do (
        if !ms! == unset (set "ms=%%F")
        if !ds! == unset (set "ds=%%G")
        if !ys! == unset (set "ys=%%H")
    )
    if !fy! == unset (
        set "fy=!ys!"
        set "fd=!ds!"
        set "fm=!ms!"
    )
    if not !fy! == unset (
        if !ys! leq !fy! (
            set "fy=!ys!"
            if !ms! leq !fm! (
                set "fm=!ms!"
                if !ds! leq !fd! (set "fd=!ds!")
            )
        )
    )
    set /a cnt=!cnt!+1
    :skp
)


:loop
for /f "delims=" %%G in ('dir /b /a:d /o:-n "%dbpth%\*"') do (
    set "str=%%G"
    set "str=!str:~-10!"
    set "str=!str: =!"
    set "str=!str:-=!"
    if !str! == !fm!_!fd!_!fy! (
        ren "%dbpth%\%%G" "!cnt! - !fm!_!fd!_!fy!"
        set /a cnt=!cnt!-1
    )
)
set /a fd=!fd!+1
if !fd! gtr 31 (
    set /a fm=!fm!+1
    set fd=1
    if !fm! gtr 12 (
        set /a fy=!fy!+1
        set fm=1
    )
)
title !cnt! - !fm!_!fd!_!fy!
if !cnt! geq 0 (goto loop)
endlocal
exit
```

Comment: You cannot use a GOTO within a parenthesized code block.  It breaks the flow of the FOR commands. You have essentially broken out of your FOR command by going to the label `skp` and then the batch files sees a right parentheses and you get your error.

Comment: Yes, that was the issue, thank you!